# c# use emgu imagebox control to display a image

Tags: c#, emgucv

I use the imagebox to display a image(imgWidth:19200, imgHeight:260),and my code is:

```
imageBox = new ImageBox();
imageBox.Size = new Size(imgWidth, imgHeight);
imageBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
MainSplitContainer.Panel1.Controls.Add(imageBox);
imageBox.Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("2.bmp");
```

But the displayed image width is only about 15000, and the right part of the image can not be displayed. How can I display the full image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an ImageBox won't do more than 15,000 pixels in width. However, have you tried setting the functional mode to Pan and Zoom? Maybe that will get you there.

Doug